# Exchange Shell - SubjectOrBodyContainsWords

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I'm attempting to create a rule per script but I'm unable to proceed because I seem to have reached a too high value...

> [PS] C:\Users\XXX\Desktop>New-InboxRule -Mailbox "Daniel.XXX"
>   -Name "Test" -SubjectOrBodyContainsWords {**"Value1","Value2","Value3","Value4","Value5","Value6","Value7","Value8","Value9","Value10","Value11","Value12","Value13","Value14","Value15","Value16","Value17","Value18","alue19","Value20","Value21","Value22","Value23","Value24","Value25","alue26","Value27","Value28","Value29","Value30","Value31","Value32","alue33","Value34","Value35","Value36","Value37","alue38","Value39","Value40","Value41","Value42","Value43","Value44","Value45","Value46","Value47","Value48","Value49","alue50","Value51","Value52","Value53","Value54","Value55","Value56","Value57","Value58"**}
>   -ApplyCategory "Common CA" -WHATIF
>
> Invoke-Command : Cannot bind parameter 'SubjectOrBodyContainsWords' to
>   the target. Exception setting "SubjectOrBodyContainsWords": "The
>   length of the property is too long. **The maximum length is 255 and the
>   length of the value provided is 570**."AtC:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Exchange\RemotePowerShell\XXXXXXXXXXXXX.psm1:20346
>   char:29
>   +             $scriptCmd = { & <<<<  $script:InvokeCommand `
>       + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [New-InboxRule], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterBindingFailed,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.NewInboxRule

If I were to setup the rule with a acceptable value and review it in Exchange Control Panel I'd only see the text as one value (one big string) instead of multiple values (which is shown if I were to create it through GUI)...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried not enclosing it in `{}`? - seems like the list is being parsed as one massive string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [about_Parsing](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847892.aspx) help file:

> When processing a command, the Windows PowerShell parser operates
>   in expression mode or in argument mode:
>
> ```
> - In argument mode, each value is treated as an expandable string 
>   unless it begins with one of the following special characters: dollar
>   sign ($), at sign (@), single quotation mark ('), double quotation
>   mark ("), or an opening parenthesis (().
> ```

Since your argument to the `SubjectOrBodyContainsWords` parameter begins with `{`, the parser treats the entire list as **one big string**. Simply remove the curly brackets (or substitute with regular parentheses):

```
New-InboxRule -Mailbox 'Daniel.XXX' -Name 'Test' -SubjectOrBodyContainsWords ("Value1","Value2","Value3","Value4","Value5","Value6","Value7","Value8","Value9","Value10","Value11","Value12","Value13","Value14","Value15","Value16","Value17","Value18","alue19","Value20","Value21","Value22","Value23","Value24","Value25","alue26","Value27","Value28","Value29","Value30","Value31","Value32","alue33","Value34","Value35","Value36","Value37","alue38","Value39","Value40","Value41","Value42","Value43","Value44","Value45","Value46","Value47","Value48","Value49","alue50","Value51","Value52","Value53","Value54","Value55","Value56","Value57","Value58")
```

To make the command a bit more readable, I would probably assign the possible values to an array beforehand:

```
$SOBCWords = @(
"Value1",
"Value2",
"Value3",
# etc
"Value56",
"Value57",
"Value58"
)
New-InboxRule -Mailbox "Daniel.XXX" -Name "Test" -SubjectOrBodyContainsWords $SOBCWords -ApplyCategory "Common CA" -WHATIF
```

Comment: Thanks for the resolution, information and the tip! I'll make use of this knowledge.