# Iterate thru SubjectOrBodyContainsWords of an Exchange transport rule

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I want to create a PowerShell script to extract a text file with a list of words specified in an Exchange Server 2016 transport rule. I'm stuck with handling the obtained list.

To get the list, I do this within Exchange Management Shell:

```
$SubjectOrBodyContainsWords = Get-TransportRule "My rule name" | Select-Object -Property SubjectOrBodyContainsWords
```

I verify that the list is correct using this:

```
$FormatEnumerationLimit = 10000
$SubjectOrBodyContainsWords | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders | Out-String -width 10000
```

The output looks like (Just an example, actual list is much much bigger):

```
{unsubscribe, mailing, blabla}
```

Now I want to iterate the list to do something with each item. I tried something like this (Just a simple example):

```
$I = 10;
foreach ($A in $SubjectOrBodyContainsWords)
{
    $I++;
    $I; 
    $A;
}
```

The problem is that it doesn't loop all the items. It looks like there is only one item.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have access to my Exchange server at the moment but just try the following suggestions. Just ask for and expand the property.

```
(Get-TransportRule "My rule name").SubjectOrBodyContainsWords

# Or

Get-TransportRule "My rule name" | 
Select-Object -ExpandProperty SubjectOrBodyContainsWords
```

Since this returns an array, you need to expand that listing.

Or you can do this to turn into a list to work with...

```
"{unsubscribe, mailing, blabla}" -replace '\s|{|}' -split ',' |  foreach {
    # Code to do something with each item
    $PSItem }

# Results
unsubscribe
mailing
blabla
```

... and

Potential duplicate of this use case

> [Exchange Shell - SubjectOrBodyContainsWords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29897435/exchange-shell-subjectorbodycontainswords)

Comment: Thank you, first proposition is working 100%. Second proposition could not be used since actual returned text may contain coma and brace which are not "escaped".